CPU spikes and stutters caused by nvidia-modeset/kthread_q
I'm experiencing a weird behavior where I have random (pretty cyclic) cpu spikes (on a single core of it), causing stuttering of the whole system (only audio isn't affected).
Running pidstat -u | sort -nr -k 7,7 | head -10
it returns "nvidia-modeset/kthread_q" at the top of the list.
Driver Version: 545.29.06
GPU 4090
Has anyone find a solution to this issue? I can't really downgrade the drivers, since I need them update for the renderer I use, but with this issue the system becomes a pain to use, the only thing that "fix it" is rebooting (as long as the issue doesn't presents itself back).
